# Depending on jar without a pom.xml using classifier results in main artifacts dependencies

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, maven, dependencies

I have a java web-app based on maven.
The main build produces a war-file. By using the assembly-plugin i create an additional jar-file that contains just a .xsd file and an empty manifest.

The xsd describes the webservice that is offered by the war-file.

To write a client for this web-app, i want to use the dependency of the jar file containing the xsd by using

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>foo.bar.myproject</groupId>
    <artifactId>mywebapp</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
    <classifier>restapi</classifier>
</dependency>
```

The restapi client jar is included the right way, but also all dependencies from the "war" are included now in my client. Which is bad.

Is there a way to switch off the dependency resolution of the "main" artifact when using the classifier?

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just create a proper Maven module for the XSD?  You just need POM file, and a directory structure with the XSD in the "main/resources" subtree.

Comment: I agree. This is common problem for Maven-based projects to minimize amount of modules, which does not work.